# propertychanged in region from other region

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism-5

I am using `WPF + MVVM` with `prism` and `unity`. 
I have three regions "`menu`", "`main`" and "`footer`". 
Now I would like to set a property in the `footerViewModel` (region "`footer`") from `MainViewModel` in region "`main`". This property should be displayed in the `footerView`. 
The change event works but it does not update the `textbox` in the `view`.

I hope someone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

This is my `MainViewModel`:

```
private CodingGuidline _selectedGuidline;
public CodingGuidline SelectedGuidline {
  get { return _selectedGuidline; }
  set
  {
    _selectedGuidline = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedGuidline);
    OnUpdateAppCodingSpecification(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}


private async void OnUpdateAppCodingSpecification(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  try
  {
    Task<CodingGuidline> result = CodingRepository.GetCodingSpecification(SelectedGuidline.Guid);
    _application.CurrentGuidline = await result;
    _container.Resolve<FooterViewModel>().OnUpdateCodingGuidline(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
  }

}
```

**Notice**: `_application` is a `static object` which provides shared information

FooterViewModel:

```
    public FooterViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
{
  _container = container;
  _application = _container.Resolve<IApplication>();
  AssemblyVersion = "Version: " + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
  WebserviceUrl = "Host: " + _application.WebserviceUrl;

  UpdateCodingGuidline += OnUpdateCodingGuidline;
}

public event EventHandler UpdateCodingGuidline;

public void OnUpdateCodingGuidline(object sender, EventArgs args) {
  if (_application.CurrentGuidline != null)
  {
    CurrentCodingSpecification = _application.CurrentGuidline.SequenceNumber + " " + _application.CurrentGuidline.Name;
  }
  else
  {
    CurrentCodingSpecification = " - ";
  }
}

private string _currentCodingSpecification;
public string CurrentCodingSpecification {
  get {
    return _currentCodingSpecification;
  }
  set {
    if (value != _currentCodingSpecification) {
      _currentCodingSpecification = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(() => CurrentCodingSpecification);
      MessageBox.Show(CurrentCodingSpecification.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

The `Messagebox` appears but the `view` doesnt show the change.

Binding in `FooterView`:

```
  <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding CurrentCodingSpecification, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services are the way to solve this issue. Create a shared service that you can inject into all your view models (and thus mock!). This manages the state and has events that can notify the vm's when a value has changed.

During the initialization of your vm's, you can subscribe to the service. When the vm's are closed, you can unsubscribe again to prevent memory leaks.

And a bit off-topic, but here are a few tips to improve your MVVM coding:

1. Instead of injecting a container, inject services (don't hide what you really need), that makes testing and other development much easier
2. Using MessageBox.Show is not smart inside vm's. How should it behave during a test? Use a service for this instead (for example, IMessageService). Then if you need to change something to the way message boxes are shown, there is 1 location for you to look at). And you can mock the messages (and even result codes).

Comment: Thanks!
I am new to PRISM and MVVM. But Services are the solution!